# Proper environment for magento2-2.3 on windows 10

Tags: magento2.3, php, composer

I'm working on Win 10 OS. And am going to install magento2-2.3 on my local computer.
Which xampp version and composer version should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: Don't!

The long answer: I tried to get magento running with Windows 10 and ran into several problems - most of them related to file-permissions, because Windows handles them very different than Linux does.

But to your problem: you are using composer version 2.0 and magento still needs version 1. You can do a `composer self-update --1`

Comment: thank you. I'll try.

Comment: Will you review this answer?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327140/installation-is-incomplete-magento2-3-6

Comment: I already saw your follow up question, but I am sorry, that is above my head and I am to polite to say "told you so" ;-)

You may try the web-setup wizard, as it should be still available with 2.3.5.

But even if you manage to install it, I dont think that the problems will stop.
In my case, it ended up in convincing my co-worker to use Linux for developing. I setup a nice docker environment, so every team-member can setup a reliable environment in minutes. 
You can also try to install magento2 in a VM - but keep the permissions in mind. Its a real hassle...

Comment: I'm trying on Ubuntu, but it's still hard to install it on my VM.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327190/install-the-magento-2-4-1-archive-on-local-computer-lubuntu-18-04-5

Answer (score 0):

Choose the one with the [recommended PHP version](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements.html#php) and Database from Magento docs.

Comment: thank you for your answering. can you solve the 2 problems in terminal?