# Install the Magento 2.4.1 archive on local computer (Lubuntu 18.04.5)

Tags: magento2, ubuntu

I followed below link.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html

I set one user permission.

But...

When I typed 'sudo composer install' in magento root folder.

```
$sudo composer install

Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package sebastian/finder-facade is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
81 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
PHP CodeSniffer Config installed_paths set to ../../magento/magento-coding-standard,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
```

Comment: no need to run composer command with root user or sudo.

Comment: what's the next step? 'http://localhost/magento/setup/' and 'http://localhost/magento/' are 500.

Comment: do the installation from command line, as the web-wizard is depcrecated and will be removed with version 2.4 of magento.
You can find a good guide here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html
You also need to setup an elasticsearch server(software), as mysql search gets removed, too *sigh

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but this one works for me.
Once you have installed all the composer packages and elasticsearch, you can proceed with the [Magento installation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html#install-magento) command, you can also check [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html#install-cli-example):

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2ce \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
--elasticsearch-host=localhost \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

If after installation there are some css and js errors, you just need to run the upgrade and static-content deploy commands.